# Is showing the package name(Android)/bundle ID(ios) a security risk?

Tags: android, mobile, ios

Suppose I release an app and accidentally publish the package name/bundle ID of the app which is suppose to be shown in development only, in a page. Is there any security concern that arises from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Does the package name need to be kept secret

No.

Here is a link to one of my apps:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.jrtapsell.appinfo&hl=en
```

(Link purely for example, it was found on the first page of google when the app name was searched for)

You can see that google provide the package name in the URL, so even if you hid it, opening the store page for an app would give it out anyway.

## Do bundle IDs need to be kept secret

No.

Following the steps [here](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/faq/finding-the-app-bundle-id/), you can get the bundle ID from the app link, so it would appear that it does not need to be kept secret.

> - Find the app online (Google for the iTunes link). For this example we use Apple Pages: https://itunes.apple.com/app/pages/id361309726?mt=8.
> - Copy the number after the id in the URL. (Here: 361309726).
> - Open https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=361309726 where you replace the ID with the one you looked up.
> - Search the output for "bundleID". In this example it looks like this (next to a bunch of other data): "bundleId":"com.apple.Pages".
>
> So for Apple, the bundle ID is com.apple.Pages.